# semflg Value of semget Function

Tags: c, posix, semaphore

Generally, some constant flag values located in sys/types.h file are passed to `semget()` function as a third argument. However, a piece of code which is given to us for a project contains such a `semget()` function call :

`sem_id = semget(SEMKEY, 1, 0) // accessing pre-defined semaphore`

semid is a global variable, and SEMKEY is a constant.

What does it mean to pass zero to semflg value ? Can we say that when accessing a semaphore which was defined previously, we set semflg parameter to zero ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly because other flags may be set even if `IPC_CREAT` is not but then are of no use. POSIX just says (about *opening*):

> A semaphore identifier with its associated semid_ds data structure and
>   its associated set of nsems semaphores (see ) is created
>   for key if one of the following is true:
>
> - The argument key is equal to IPC_PRIVATE.
> - The argument key does not already have a semaphore identifier
>     associated with it and (semflg & IPC_CREAT) is non-zero.

So, of course, *semflg=0* imply *no creation*. But *no creation* does not imply *semflg=0*.

Comment: In this case, we do not have to use zero flag value to access a pre-defined semaphore. The rule which we have to obey to access a semaphore which was defined previously is to avoid using the flag values which you mentioned above, since they are used for creating a semaphore. Could I understand it properly ?

Comment: Yes provided that IPC_CREAT is not set, everything will be ok.